# how get all id from json to array on other variables - jmeter

Tags: arrays, json, jmeter

I have two JSON. In the both I have name. How can I get names from first JSON and add to array? Later I want do this same with second JSON later i want both array compare? How can I do this?

```
jsonArray1 = [{'name': "doug", 'id':5}, {'name': "dofug", 'id':23}];     
jsonArray2 = [{'name': "goud", 'id':1}, {'name': "doaaug", 'id':52}];
```

for example I want:

```
a = [doug, dofug] b = [goud, doaaug]
```

and later check if these are the same arrays

i don't know how can i do this in jmeter, help

Answer (score 0):

1. To convert one array to another:

   - Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns first JSON Array
   - Put the following code into "Script" area:

     ```
     def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
     builder(com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(prev.getResponseDataAsString(),'$..name').collect())
     vars.put('array1', builder.toPrettyString())
     ```
   - That's it, you should be able to access the newly generated JSON Array as `${array1}` where required
2. Repeat the same steps for the second JSON array.

   [image]
3. There are several options on how to compare 2 JSON entities, depending on what you're trying to achieve you can go for:

   - [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion)
   - a [JSR223 Assertion and a 3rd-party library](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-easiest-way-to-compare-rest-api-responses-using-jmeter) like:

     - [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)
     - [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)
     - [JSONassert](https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert)